# How can I build a square quadtree

Tags: data-structures, game-development, quadtree

How can I build a square quadtree ?! I have a 2D game with squared-shape players and I want to detect collision between them , I want to use quadtree but all sources I found explains quad tree which just store points ، anyone can help?

Comment: Are you asking how to use a quadtree with square items rather than points? If so, each item will have the potential to reside in multiple quadtree cells. If the cells are square and the items are smaller than the cells, then an item can reside in a maximum of 4 cells, otherwise more than 4. So that's the sort of thing you'll need to take into account. Also, if your goals are practical rather than e.g. educational, a uniform grid or even no broad phase at all might be suitable, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: In addition to points, store bounding boxes for each point. Use those for your collision check.

Comment: Another approach (which I think is the usual approach) is to store a player simply in the smallest cell that it fits in. No need to have it reside in multiple cells.

Comment: thank u .. I build a one which I can store sqared items